# PHP Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: php, cross-domain

just wanted to find a solution to this.  I am within System A and I make the following call

```
$("#page-form").submit(function(event){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://someOtherUrl/process.php",
          data: {
              'mobNumber': $("#mobile").val()
          }
      }).done(function (response) {
              alert(response);
          });       
  })
```

Now this makes a call to a PHP file on another server.  This PHP file does nothing at the moment, I simply have

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

var_dump("1");
```

However I am getting a cross origin request blocked error.  Why would this be happening?

As a side note, I have no access to the server running System A, so it has to be done on my server where the PHP file sits.

Thanks

**Update**

Server seems to have this
**Response headers**

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 25 Jun 2015 12:31:50 GMT
Expires Thu, 25 Jun 2015 12:31:50 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
Transfer-Encoding  chunked
Vary  Accept-Encoding
x-ua-compatible IE=edge
```

**Request headers**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

Comment: Is the value in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` the same as in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` ?

Comment: Would Access-Control-Request-Headers have to be set in System A?  If so, I am not too sure what they are

Comment: Yes the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` comes from System A. Take a   look at what is being requested from System A using dev-tools.

Comment: Did you try to comment out the `allow-methods` and `allow-headers`, just to check if the `allow-origin` is working?

Comment: Yeah, same result.  I have updated the op with what I see in firebug

Comment: Can you also show the response headers ? Unless the request isn't made at all.

Comment: The request is blocked so I do not have a response

Comment: I'm going to be annoying about this but are you certain the request is blocked before it's beng sent ? Under CORS, the browser generally has to check the response to decide whether or not to block.

Comment: Not to sure how I would check this?  All I know is that I receive a cross domain block message in the console

Comment: Since you said Firebug: In Firefox, you have to enable "net" events in the browser console and you should see clickable [http...] links on the right of requested urls that will open a window with the headers inside.

Comment: I have updated the op.  I have removed a couple of things but thats most of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81532/discussion-between-spenibus-and-nick-price).

Comment: At this point we know system B is not sending out the CORS headers. There is however not enough information to provide a definite answer as to why this happens. Maybe the server unsets certain headers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the .htaccess file present at the root folder on https://someOtherUrl/  :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```